# How to display atributes in HTML with nodejs and expressjs?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have an application with Node.js, Express and HTML. In a JavaScript file I´m calling responde.render to show a HTML page, passing any variables, like that:

```
response.render('agent.html', {name: name, phome: phone});
```

My question is: how can I use **name** and **phone** in a HTML file? I need to set name value in output tag (). Can I do this with script? How?

I know how to do this with jade, but it's not my case.

Ty guys.

Comment: You need to use a view engine such as Jade or others.

Comment: EJS is a view engine that is very close to HTML. I've got an example here on how to use it: http://hectorcorrea.com/#/blog/introduction-to-node-js/51 (look under Express.js and Templates)

Comment: I'm trying to use EJS. I call response.render('agent.html', {name: 'aaaa'});, and in HTML script I try access <%= this.name %>, but I have an error log saying ReferenceError: aaaa is not defined. Can you help me guys? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML file is static HTML.  You must use a template engine.

Comment: You are saying that I have to use Jade, for example? And if I want to use pure HTML, there are no way?

Comment: Use [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/). It's an extension of HTML so it's the closest you can get to use pure HTML.

Comment: @HenioJR You don't have to use Jade, but you have to use something.  Pure HTML leaves you no way to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks @Brad and bduran, I'll try to use EJS. I'll post the result.

Comment: I'm trying to use EJS. I call **response.render('agent.html', {name: 'aaaa'});**, and in HTML script I try access **<%= this.name %>**, but I have an error log saying **ReferenceError: aaaa is not defined**. Can you help me guys? Ty

Comment: @HenioJR Post a new question with that problem.